# Is it normal for 2k users to 'hijack' edits? (Coming in after a major edit, making miniscule changes and using the previous edit comment)

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33927433/revisions) question. When I went to see my approved edit (it's one of my first so I wanted to double check my work) I was puzzled as to why I wasn't listed as the editor.

I checked the edit history to find out why this was, maybe there was something wrong with my edit? I saw this user had added 2 spaces to my edit and used the same edit comment. Looking further into it I saw that they had also been the one that reviewed (and passed) my edit. Is this normal or expected behaviour? Looking at their user page I found they do a lot of edits this way, but I assume that could be hem being a newly 2k user.

Comment: The edit summary is automatically re-used for the "improvement" edit; it can be changed manually if the reviewer so desires.

Comment: As 2k users can make edits without peer approval needed, they can use such action to just get your edit through more quickly. I'm doing so sometimes if I think the edit is essential and should be shown a soon as possible.

Comment: It's not really "hijacking". It's just building on top.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy Yes, this is me misunderstanding the 'don't post trivial edits' rule and not knowing of improvement edits. Not knowing of the improvement feature I thought the user was attempting to use other people's edits to 'sneak in' trivial edits by copying the edit comment.

Comment: @Knells What is the point of doing that, though? Edits are for tidying up posts, not adding anything of value. Although it shows the last person who edited it, they don't get any credit for the post - whether it be reputation on SO (for >2k) or simply social recognition. Further, your name is still there in the edit history.

Comment: SO works in wonderful ways. Example: someone might stay at 2100 internet points because they donate a lot of bounties and/or make it a habit to max out the daily downvotes on terrible answers. The number of points someone has doesn't say anything about them.

Comment: @Rob At the time I thought they would also get +2 rep for editing.

Comment: @Gimby I definitely agree there, this site is awesome and I definitely plan to hand out bounties when I get a bit more rep to spare. In this case I checked the reputation audit to see exactly when the user first reached >2k rep, which was recently. I figured similar precautions apply to any new privileges as new access to any site feature (e.g. new answerer or asker)